# How to create multiple receivers in Azure Eventhub to avoide duplicates?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have one producer which is sending the events to Event hub.
I want to create 2 receivers to receive events from eventhub. How to implement that.

The code for receiver:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventHubSharedKeyCredential, EventData, EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore

#Eventhub access credentials
connection_str = ****
consumer_group = '$Default'
eventhub_name = ****

#Blobstorage Storage credentials
storage_connection_str = ****
container_name = ****
storageAccount = ****

#For checkpointing in Blob storage
checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(storage_connection_str, container_name)

#Initiate BlobServiceClient to access the Blob storage
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('container_name') #Dump final data to the Blob storage in append mode.

try:
  container_client.create_container()  #Create new Container in the service
  properties = container_client.get_container_properties()
except ResourceExistsError:
  print("Container already exists.")

#Instantiate a new BlobClient
#blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("data.csv")


def get_messages():
client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

def on_event_batch(partition_context, events):
    #log.info("Partition {}, Received count: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id, len(events)))
    print("Received event from partition {}".format(
        partition_context.partition_id))  # Since no partition is defined so partition = 0 by default.
    if (len(events) == 0):
        client.close()  # closing the client if there is no event triggered.

    else:
        for event in events:
            list_ = event.body_as_json()
            # Update checkpoint
            partition_context.update_checkpoint()
try:
    with client:
        client.receive_batch(
            on_event_batch=on_event_batch,
            PARTITION="0",)
            #starting_position="-1", )  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped receiving.')

get_messages()
```

I have created 2 copies of this code with names **consumer1.py** and **consumer2.py**. But both these consumers receive the same events every time.

So for example I send 100 events then I want these two consumers to run in parallel and divide those 100 events among themselves and avoiding duplicates. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the same consumer group for the two running instances ? Ideally you should have partition per consumer app, having multiple readers in a single partition can led to duplicates

Comment: Yes @Jdresc, I'm using the same consumer group. Exactly I wanna create multiple partitions for each receiver, how to achieve that, any idea ?

Comment: Increase the number of partitions on the Event Hub depending on much concurrency you want, then you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventprocessorhost.abstract_event_processor.abstracteventprocessor?view=azure-python-previous that will load balance the partition ownership automatically

Comment: Can you please paste some samples for my requirement? @Jdresc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution to create multiple consumers under the same consumer group which can consume the events parallelly and also should share the load among each other.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventHubSharedKeyCredential, EventData, EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore

#Eventhub access credentials
connection_str = ****
consumer_group = '$Default'
eventhub_name = ****

#Blobstorage Storage credentials
storage_connection_str = ****
container_name = ****
storageAccount = ****


#For checkpointing in Blob storage
checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(storage_connection_str, container_name)

#Initiate BlobServiceClient to access the Blob storage
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('nsc-container') 
#Dump final data to the Blob storage in append mode.

try:
  container_client.create_container()  #Create new Container in the service
  properties = container_client.get_container_properties()
except ResourceExistsError:
  print("Container already exists.")

#Instantiate a new BlobClient
#blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("data.csv")

def get_messages():
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name, checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,)

    def on_event_batch(partition_context, events):
        #log.info("Partition {}, Received count: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id, len(events)))
        print("Received event from partition {}".format(
        partition_context.partition_id))  # Since no partition is defined so partition = 0 by default.
    line_count = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    cnt = 0
    if (len(events) == 0):
        client.close()  # closing the client if there is no event triggered.

    else:

        for event in events:
            list_ = event.body_as_json()
            cnt += 1
            # Update checkpoint
            partition_context.update_checkpoint()
        print("Number of events received: ",cnt)
    line_count = line_count+ cnt
    end_time = time.time()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("\nTotal Received {} records in {} seconds.".format(line_count, run_time))

try:

    with client:
        client.receive_batch(
            on_event_batch=on_event_batch,) # With specified partition_id, load-balance will be disabled

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped receiving.')

get_messages()
```

Now create as many copies of the code and save them as **consumer_1.py** and so on. Also, make sure to keep the number of partitions equal to the number of consumers for best efficiency.